# Write algorithm for creating vector of vector lengths

Tags: c++, stl

I have a vector of vectors of ints.  Each of the 2nd tier vectors can be of different lengths.  I would like to create of vector of ints where each value is the length of the corresponding vector divided by a constant.

For instance:

```
std::vector<int> a = { 1, 2, 3 };
std::vector<int> b = { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
const int kDivisor = 10;
std::vector<std::vector<int>> collection;
collection.push_back(a);
collection.push_back(b);
std::vector<double> scaled_lengths;

for (auto v : collection) {
    scaled_lengths.push_back(static_cast<double>(v.size()) / kDivisor);
}
```

Desired output is scaled_length = [.3, .4]

Can I use STL algorithms to get this output?

Thanks!

Comment: You can (with `std::transform`), but your for loop will be much more clear for such a simple, specialized task.

Comment: I can't think of anything simpler than what you have,

Comment: Please reconsider the "STL" tag, which refers to an obsolete (while still indirectly influential) library. Make sure you read tag description before adding them!

Comment: @BenjaminLindley, I am trying to learn the c++ STL algorithms.  I had read that using algorithms is *always* preferable to writing loops.  I agree that the transform solution looks more complicated, do you think it has value because of showing intent / performance / minimizing chances to write errors in loops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It isn't simpler, but maybe you want it as a building block for something bigger.

```
    scaled_lengths.resize(collection.size());
    std::transform(collection.begin(), collection.end(), scaled_lengths.begin(),
                   [=](auto &v) { return static_cast<double>(v.size())/kDivisor; });
```